# Regex for finding matching on one part of a String and not another part

Tags: java, regex

`(appendCsrfToken).+(\.do\?\w)`
matches on a String like...
`document.forms[0].action = appendCsrfToken("search.do?lname=Smith");`

What I would like to do is find Strings that have the `.do?` portion but don't have the `appendCsrfToken` portion.  For instance...
`document.forms[0].action = "search.do?lname=Smith";`

I thought that the following would negation would work but I'm getting no matches when I test it
`(^appendCsrfToken).+(\.do\?\w)`

How do I properly negate the `appendCsrfToken` to get the match I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `^` for negation only works in character classes. You need a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The easiest way is to look from the beginning of the string (`^`) all the way through for `appendCsrfToken` with a *negated* lookahead. If that works, then go ahead and match the `do?`:

```
^(?!.*appendCsrfToken).*(\.do\?\w)
```

[Demo.](http://fiddle.re/b1hua)

Comment: Yes indeed - that does the trick - what I don't quite understand is the `^(?!` portion.  Does the article you link explain this (I haven't yet read it)?

Comment: @ZackMacomber yes, that's why I linked it ^^. The `^` and the `(?!...)` are unrelated. `^` (outside of a character class) is an anchor that matches only at the beginning of the string (without consuming any characters). The `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead, which fails if its subpattern matches - but *doesn't* actually consume what's matched by the subpattern... hence it *looks* ahead. But the article explains this much better than I ever could.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use negative lookbehind. Here's the solution

```
^(?<!.*appendCsrfToken).*(\\.do\\?\\w)
```